# How to code a button to change the ViewController from one to another without creating a new one

Tags: objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

- Right now when I press the `UIButton` to that page, it brings up a new page without the information that have been there before.
- Right now we do it by press control and drag the `UIButton` to the `UIViewController` and choose modal.

For more detail, I'm making the dressing app. Everytime I choose a new cloth, it takes me to the model page without the clothes that are already selected before.

Comment: Can you please clarify this more with sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the data before you left the page and loaded it in the next page,
so you will have the data for the next page.

Create a NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

To Save Object

```
[defaults setObject:YOUR_OBJECT forKey:@"YOUR_KEY"];
```

To Load Your Object

```
YOUR_LOADED_OBJECT = [defaults objectForKey:@"YOUR_KEY"];
```